# Step definition is not getting recognized by the Runner file

Tags: selenium, cucumber

Methods in the step definition are not recognized by the runner file. though I have added all the methods in the step definition file still displaying "You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:" on the console
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QZ6T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVEwv.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have provided wrong package reference in the test runner class.

com.ba package ref is not correct in your code

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = "",
        glue = "Useless"  //This is your package where step def files are present
)
```

Comment: @kishore naidu: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer if your issue is resolved